# How I can safely reference to an std::vector element?

Tags: c++

I will like to create a struct that holds a higher state for other structs.

I tried to create it like this, but I recently found that returning a pointer to an element of an std::vector is not safe, since that pointer can change.

```
struct Foo {
  std::string &context;
  std::string content;

  Foo(std::string &context, std::string content) : context(context), content(content) {}
}

struct Bar {
  std::string context;
  std::vector<std::string> manyFoos;

  Foo* addFoo(std::string content) {
    manyFoos.emplace_back(context, content);
    return &manyFoos[manyFoos.size() - 1];
  }
}

struct Example {
  Bar bar;
  Foo* fooA;
  Foo* fooB;

  Example() {
    fooA = bar.addFoo("Hello");
    fooB = bar.addFoo("World");
  }
}
```

What could be a good and safe way of doing this?

Comment: Use some other container instead of std::vector?

Comment: ^^ such as `std::list<T>` for example

Comment: There is any alternative in the standard library?

Comment: I just mentioned one

Comment: Oh, and you are strongly advised to delete `Bar`'s copy constructor, due to the fact that `Foo`s are storing a reference to `Bar`'s member. If, upon doing that, your compiler starts complaining (about the deleted copy constructor) you will owe your compiler's a thank-you note for finding a bug in your code.

Comment: Yes, I will like to avoid using pointers... not sure if there is other way

Comment: You can have vector of share_ptr & return weak_ptr, this way you can make sure correct referecing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have vector of shared_ptr & return weak_ptr, this way you can make sure correct referencing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Foo {
    std::string &context;
    std::string content;

    Foo(std::string &context, std::string content) : context(context), content(content) {}
};

struct Bar {
    std::string context;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> manyFoos;

    std::weak_ptr<Foo> addFoo(std::string content) {
        auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>(context, content);
        manyFoos.emplace_back(foo);
        return foo;
    }
};

void printFoo(std::weak_ptr<Foo> foo)
{
    // Here we are checking weak_ptr expiry
    std::cout << (foo.expired() ? "Foo Expired" : foo.lock()->content) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Bar bar;
    std::weak_ptr<Foo> fooA;
    std::weak_ptr<Foo> fooB;

    fooA = bar.addFoo("Hello");
    fooB = bar.addFoo("World");

    printFoo(fooA);
    printFoo(fooB);

    // erase last element
    bar.manyFoos.pop_back();
    printFoo(fooB);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
World
Foo Expired
```

Answer (score 2):

> What could be a good and safe way of doing this?

Saving the couple (vector reference, `Foo`'s index), assuming `Foo`s are only added at the back.

With a bit of syntaxic sugar:

```
struct Bar {
  std::string context;
  std::vector<Foo> manyFoos;

  struct FooProxy
  {
    std::vector<Foo>& foos;
    std::vector<Foo>::size_type index;
    operator Foo() { return foos[index]; }
  };

  auto addFoo(std::string content) {
    manyFoos.emplace_back(context, content);
    return FooProxy{manyFoos, manyFoos.size()-1};
  }
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/436fec68502a318a)